# C# Store App / Service - Passing JSON from service to client via Controller

Tags: c#, json, controller, windows-phone-8.1

When I invoke the following to a custom controller to return data to my client (`Windows Phone 8.1 app`):

```
var _lines = await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<List<Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line>>("lines", System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Get, new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"url", "http://api.tfl.gov.uk/Line"}
            });
```

I received the following `Exception`:-

`FileNotFoundException was caught`

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Serialization, 
Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one 
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However, I successfully parse the `JSON` data via the controller and I also have no references to the above dll in my Windows Phone application.

[Update]

The data is deserializing using System.Runtime.Serialization 4.0.0.0 on the client side (which is targeting .NET 4.5). I am using a third party DLL found here (api.tfl.gov.uk) which contains all of the data transfer objects required to map the data from the JSON into an object structure.

I have tested this DLL also within a console application and runs as expected, deserializing and mapping data etc; could the issue be that the DLL I'm using containing DataContract and DataMember annotations cannot be used as a reference within the Windows Phone 8.1 app?

I say this because I have a solution whereby I 'copy' the DTO modes in the DLL into plain models using the same code (minus Serialization annotations) and the JSON then is able to deserialize and map to those in the phone.

So the solution are present is to create my own models, however if you've any other ideas/workarounds that would be great to know in the future where I can just reference the third party DLL.

Any ideas?

--David

Comment: Note: This occurs when calling the API directly and parsing the JSON locally in the mobile app.

Comment: Note: Running Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 with Update 4